# Gradle could not find org.igniterealtime.smack:smackx:3.4.1

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, smack

I have a project using smack.  My gradle build file contains this line:

```
compile group: 'org.igniterealtime.smack', name: 'smackx', version: '3.4.1'
```

When I run `gradlew build` I get the following result:

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
>
> > Could not find org.igniterealtime.smack:smackx:3.4.1.
>
> Searched in the following locations: ...
>   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/igniterealtime/smack/smackx/3.4.1/smackx-3.4.1.jar
>   ...

I copied the compile group line directly from [this website](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.igniterealtime.smack/smackx/3.4.1) so I believe it is correct.

Can anyone tell me what is causing the error?

Comment: Smack 3 is very old and has known security issues. Consider using Smack 4.1 instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From that link, the JAR at version 3.4.1 is not available in Maven central (where your build is currently configured to search for artifacts). The [highest version in Maven central](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/igniterealtime/smack/smackx/) is 3.2.1. It is only available in the Atlassian Maven repo. You need to add the Atlassian 3rd-Party Repository to your build to pick it up.

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.atlassian.com/3rdparty/'
    }
}
```